# 2 Sub references as arguments in perl

Tags: perl

I have perl function I dont what does it  do?
my what does min in perl?
@ARVG what does mean?

```
sub getArgs
{
my $argCnt=0;
my %argH;

for my $arg (@ARGV)
{
    if ($arg =~ /^-/)   # insert this entry and the next in the hash table
    {
        $argH{$ARGV[$argCnt]} = $ARGV[$argCnt+1];
    }
    $argCnt++;
}
return %argH;}
```

Comment: It's trying to extract command line options and put them in `%argh`. It's buggy, though. (Doesn't handle values that start with `-` properly. Getopt::Long is commonly used to do this.

Comment: Is your code really formatted badly? I'd take that as a big clue the the original author doesn't really know what he's doing? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Code like that makes David sad...

Here's a reformatted version of the code doing the indentations correctly. That makes it so much easier to read. I can easily tell where my `if` and loops start and end:

```
sub getArgs {
    my $argCnt = 0;
    my %argH;

    for my $arg ( @ARGV ) {
        if ( $arg =~ /^-/ )  { # insert this entry and the next in the hash table
            $argH{ $ARGV[$argCnt] } = $ARGV[$argCnt+1];
        }
        $argCnt++;
    }
    return %argH;
}
```

The `@ARGV` is what is passed to the program. It is an array of all the arguments passed. For example, I have a program `foo.pl`, and I call it like this:

```
foo.pl one two three four five
```

In this case, `$ARGV` is set to the list of values `("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")`. The name comes from a similar variable found in the C programming language.

The author is attempting to parse these arguments. For example:

```
foo.pl -this that -the other
```

would result in:

```
$arg{"-this"} = "that";
$arg{"-the"}  = "other";
```

---

I don't see `min`. Do you mean `my`?

This is a wee bit of a complex discussion which would normally involve package variables vs. lexically scoped variables, and how Perl stores variables. To make things easier, I'm going to give you a sort-of incorrect, but technically wrong answer: If you use the (strict) pragma, and you should, you have to declare your variables with `my` before they can be used. For example, here's a simple two line program that's wrong. Can you see the error?

```
$name = "Bob";
print "Hello $Name, how are you?\n";
```

Note that when I set `$name` to "Bob", `$name` is with a lowercase `n`. But, I used `$Name` (upper case *N*) in my `print` statement. As it stands, now. Perl will print out "Hello, how are you?" without a care that I've used the wrong variable name. If it's hard to spot an error like this in a two line program, imagine what it would be like in a 1000 line program.

By using *strict* and forcing me to declare variables with `my`, Perl can catch that error:

```
use strict;
use warnings;  # Another Pragma that should always be used

my $name = "Bob";
print "Hello $Name, how are you doing\n";
```

Now, when I run the program, I get the following error:

> Global symbol "$Name" requires explicit package name at (line # of `print` statement)

This means that `$Name` isn't defined, and Perl points to where that error is.

When you define variables like this, they are *in scope* with in the *block* where it's defined. A block could be the code contained in a set of curly braces or a `while`, `if`, or `for` statement. If you define a variable with `my` outside of these, it's defined to the end of the file.

Thus, by using `my`, the variables are only defined inside this subroutine. And, the `$arg` variable is only defined in the `for` loop.

---

One more thing:

The person who wrote this should have used the [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) module. There's a major bug in their code:

For example:

```
foo.pl -this that -one -two
```

In this case, my hash looks like this:

```
$args{'-this'} = "that";
$args{'-one'}  = "-two";
$args{'-two'}  = undef;
```

If I did this:

```
if ( defined $args{'-two'} ) {
    ...
}
```

I would not execute the `if` statement.

Also:

```
foo.pl -this=that -one -two
```

would also fail.

Answer (score 1):

`@ARGV` is a special variable (refer to [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)):

> @ARGV
>
> The array @ARGV contains the command-line arguments intended for the
>   script. $#ARGV is generally the number of arguments minus one, because
>   $ARGV[0] is the first argument, not the program's command name itself.
>   See $0 for the command name.

Perl documentation is also available from your command line:

```
perldoc -v @ARGV
```